# Copy texture binded to FBO to another OpenGL context

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, fbo

I am trying to copy texture from FBO created in one context to another context. I am using Qt 4.8.3 and QGLFramebufferObject class, OpenGL 2.1.
i created two contexts with widgets using qt class `QGLWidget`

I was trying using blitFramebuffer method to copy full FBO to another context, but not succeeded. How can i copy texture from FBO, or maybe there is another way to transfer visual content from FBO.

The FBO is created with such parameters

```
new QGLFramebufferObject(arraySize, arraySize, QGLFramebufferObject::NoAttachment, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_ALPHA);
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you are trying to copy data from framebuffer to texture? If yes, why `blitFramebuffer` didn't work? Any errors? Also, how do you create your OpenGL context? Have you specified, that these two contexts should share resources?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i created two contexts using qt class `QGLWidget`
I was trying blit using this method: 
`QGLFramebufferObject::blitFramebuffer(targetFBO_context2, rect, sourceFBO_context1, rect, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) `
than i bind targetFBO_context2 texture and uses `glDrawArrays`
I dont know about sharing resources between context, i'll look for this topic
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got two solutions for this problem

1. copy texture attached to the FBO using [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml) 

   `uint * pixels = new uint[FBO_WIDTH * FBO_HEIGHT];
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, someFBO->texture());
   glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);`
2. share resources as Mateusz Grzejek said:
   in qt you must put a parameter to the constructor `shareWidget` of `QGLWidget`, read more [here QGLWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#QGLWidget)
   e.g. `GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0, QGLWidget * shareWidget = 0);`
   and then when you creates two GL widgets use style like this

`GLWidget *glWidget = new GLWidget(this);
GLWidget *glWidget2 = new GLWidget(this, glWidget);`

Comment: I think the method is way too slow, which copies data between CPU and GPU. blitFramebuffer should be able to work. At least we used it successfully to copy textures. Try to debug into the usage of the arguments.